usbip not finding usb devices on WSL
This command
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-204-generic/usbip list --local
is returning no listed devices (and no errors), even though I have a Ledger Nano S plugged in and running the wallet app.  I should have the version of WSL that supports access from WSL to usb devices
Windows 11 Home Version 10.0.26100 Build 26100
From the PowerShell window:
wsl --version
WSL version: 2.3.26.0
Kernel version: 5.15.167.4-1
WSLg version: 1.0.65
MSRDC version: 1.2.5620
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26100.1-240331-1435.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.26100.2605
I'm stumped. Looked all over stackoverflow, askubuntu, and tezos stack exchange. Found some old articles, but nothing that gets me past the empty response.  Tried running with --debug before the list command, and a boatload of output that tells me nothing.
